# Making win7 user non admin hides it

Tags: windows-7

I installed Windows 7 on a new PC.

The account created during installation, is to be used for demos and thus we don't want it to be an admin.

I enabled the admin account and made the 'demos' account non-admin, but now I can't see the demos account when starting the PC! I only see Administrartor.

What can I do?

EDIT: Forgot to mention account doesn't have a password.... will that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that the user account created during windows setup was added to the Administrators group but not the Users group, so when I removed it from the Administrators group, it no longer was shown.

Adding it into the Users group solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start -> Run -> compmgmt.msc (or hit WinKey + R).

Under System Tools, you should see Local Users and Groups.  Expand that, and go to Users, and select the user account of interest.  Make sure that the account is *not* disabled.

Comment: The account isn't disabled as I used it when making it a non-admin account and to enable the Administrator account. I have also confirmed this! I have now found the solution.... I think!

Comment: @neildeadman just so you know, if the solution you found works, you can post it as an answer and accept it (yes, to your own question).

Comment: thanks, I will once I have confirmed it is the solution! :)